# Breaking out of while loop is not working

Tags: python

I have a code sample where the problem is:

```
while True:
  for i in range(3):
    i = input()
    if i == 'quit'
      break
    else:
      print('Try again')
```

When I type quit in my input it doesn't break out of the code. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why do you need for loop?

Comment: The break statement is breaking out of the for loop. You need to create a variable outside the for loop with its value set to false.  In the  `if i == 'quit'`, you need to  set that variable to true. Then outside the for loop you need to check if that variable is true. If so, break out of the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
while True:
  i = input()
  if i == 'quit'
    break
  print('Try again')
```

I removed for loop because it has no usage and for loop is the reason of break not working because you are breaking out of for loop and not the while loop. I also removed else in if statement.

Comment: Oh, it's working, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You're just breaking out of the `for` loop, not the `while` loop. If you want to get out of `while` loop then use this code:

```
while True:
  for i in range(3):
    i = input()
    if i == 'quit':
      break
    else:
      print('Try again')
      continue
  break
```

Answer (score 0):

NOTE - The following answer(s) assume(s) that you need the for loop for some purpose.

---

The break statement is breaking out of the for loop. You need to create a variable outside the for loop with its value set to false. In the if i == 'quit', you need to set that variable to true. Then outside the for loop you need to check if that variable is true. If so, break out of the while loop.

So the final code would look something like this :-

```
while True:
  exit_loop = false
  for i in range(3):
    i = input()
    if i == 'quit':
      exit_loop = true
      break
    else:
      print('Try again')
  if exit_loop: break
```

---

EDIT:

Another solution could be to raise an error and handle it using the try statement.

```
while True:
  try:
    for i in range(3):
      i = input()
      if i == 'quit':
        raise ValueError('')
      else:
        print('Try again')
  except Exception as e:
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

As Vishwa Mittar explained your code "break" works only for inner loop not for outer loop So you can use flag for while loop instead of bool as below

````py
flag = True
while flag:
    for i in range(3):
        i = input()
        if i == 'quit':
            flag=False
            break
        else:
            print('Try again')```
````